# Failed to connect to mailserver when using gmail and SSL or TSL

Tags: php, wamp, sendmail

I read many posts about that and always followed the suggested solutions,
but nothing is working for me.
I have a WAMP-System running using xampp on localhost.
I try to send a mail via the PHP mail()-function. But it does not work
I always getting the error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

my php.ini looks like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=ssl://smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = example@me.com
```

My php-file:

```
<?php

//Einstellungen für den Mail-Versand
/*ini_set("SMTP","tls://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","587");
*/

 $to = "my@email.com";  

 $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];  
 $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];    
 $email = $_POST['email'];          
 $msg = $_POST['message'];          

 $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $all=
"firstname: ".$firstname."\r\
".
"lastname: ".$lastname."\r\
".
"email: ".$email."\r\
".
"message: ".$msg."\r\
";

 $succes = mail($to, "Subject", $all, $headers);

 if ($succes)
    echo "Ihre Nachricht wurde erfolgreich verschickt.";
 else
     echo "Fehler beim Versenden der Nachricht.";
?>
```

I also tried it with TLS as you can see in the comment above.
Open SSl is enabled (phpinfo told me)
I use the MecuryMail-Server and i used a tutorial to configure it.

When i set the SMTP to localhost and Port 25, it gives me the error:

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry

Do you think its a MailServer Configuration issue?
or is something wrong with my php-File?

Comment: I would highly recommend [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for doing this. It opens a socket and can help you to better debug your mail sending problems

Comment: I fixed it. There was an error in the configuration. For other people get stuck on this.. read the XAMPP "How-to Guides". Just call localhost and in the top menu you find this